# Determining the relative path

Tags: java, file, path, relative-path

I have this working absolute path

```
String path = "C:/projects/ISI7/Releases/Release_15.2/EXT_JS/src/main/webapp/WEB-
INF/classes/commonComponents/ApplicationResources_"+ language + ".properties";
```

I want to get the relative path. I thought the relative path was:

```
String path = "classes/commonComponents/ApplicationResources_"+ language + ".properties";
```

but I get fileNotFound exception

what i have tried is:

```
String path = "commonComponents/ApplicationResources_"+ language + ".properties";
```

and it didn't work either. Using JDK 1.6 and Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure about your working dir try this:

```
File f = new File(".");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I got   C:\projects\ISI7\Releases\Release_15.2\EXT_JS\src\main\java\com\export\. which is a completely different  folder, where I have my .java files. After mvn install war:inplace the files are copied to the C:\projects\ISI7\Releases\Release_15.2\EXT_JS\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF folder (which has classes and inside classes common Components) @cark